# Make Cancel button in search bar active after search button tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have search bar and cancel button, after search button tapped, it display the result but cancel button is inactive and i need to click twice to make it work and back to the initial result. How to make cancel button active after the search result appear?

here's my code

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.endEditing(true)
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
    filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!, scope: "All")
    print(searchBar.text)
}
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.text = ""
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
    database = dataUtuh
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

I already implement `UISearchBarDelegate` and `searchBar.delegate = self` on my viewDidLoad

Comment: may be you can try with main thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience if you do `searchBar.endEditing(true)` then the cancel button is disabled, try adding this after that to see if its work, im also using it in my project:

```
func enableCancelButton (searchBar : UISearchBar) {
    for view1 in searchBar.subviews {
        for view2 in view1.subviews {
            if view2.isKindOfClass(UIButton) {
                let button = view2 as! UIButton
                button.enabled = true
                button.userInteractionEnabled = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I call the function after `searchBar.endEditing(true)` in `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` and still doesnt work

Comment: put it in the last line of `searchBarSearchButtonClicked ` and check again, not sure why you called `setShowsCancelButton ` so many times

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly, I will not be able to without your help

Answer (score 5):

Put the code to enable the cancel button in search bar's  `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` delegate method
In this way after the search bar will be clicked the cancel button will be still enabled.

so the complete code snippet would be

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.endEditing(true)
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
    print(searchBar.text)


    for view in searchBar.subviews {
        for subview in view.subviews {
            if let button = subview as? UIButton {
                button.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Happy coding...